# PHP Number Format to 12 characters

Tags: php, math

I have the following numbers:
12.00
12.45

I want those to convert to 
000000001200
000000001245

What is the best way to do that?

The total is 12 characters, the last 2 digit is for 2 digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "it simply works"-solution

```
echo str_pad((int) ($value * 100), '0', 12, \STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

http://php.net/str-pad

You can look at [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) for more techically solutions.

Comment: I think `sprintf('%012d', $value * 100)` is much cleaner solution.

Comment: @meze Often realised, that many don't understand the format-syntax (and sometimes are too lazy to have a look at the manual ... grmpf) and I forget the format myself often too. You should make an answer of this comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use number_format and printf to remove any decimals and have zero padding.  I included it in a function below:

```
<?php
function twelvedigits($a){
    $a = number_format($a, 2, '', '');
    printf("%012s\n", $a);
}
$one = 12.45;
$two = 12.00;

echo '$one: ';
twelvedigits($one);
echo '$two: ';
twelvedigits($two);

?>
```

See the example here: http://ideone.com/I3UOmQ